# Telescope Scheduling

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose we want to observe the stars using a unique telescope. have a list of each of the stars that will be visible in the sky. Each star appears inside a certain time window with the possibility of multiple stars to overlap, so the group assigned a value to each star indicating the desirability of observing it.

The input consists on a list L of time intervals in which the stars will be available for observation. Each interval i∈L consists of the following elements:

-a start time S​i​​ after which the star will be available for observation;

-a finish time F​i​​ after which the star will no longer be available;

-a positive integer D​i​​ indicating the desirability to see the i-th star.

In order to satisfy the desirability of seeing the i-th star, the observations must be performed by the telescope for the entire time period from S​i​​ to F​i​​ (inclusive). Thus, two stars, i and j, are not simultaneously observable (i.e. they conflict) if the time interval [Si,Fi] intersects the time interval [S​j​​,F​j​​]. Given the list L of time intervals of availability of the stars in the sky, the optimization problem is to schedule the observations in a non-conflicting way so as to maximize the total desirability of the observations that are included in the schedule. Standard input

The first line of the input contains a positive integer N indicating the number of stars.

Each of the following i lines, 1≤i≤N, indicates the start (Si​​) and finish (Fi​​) times of each star together with the desirability Di of seeing that star.

The output should be the sum of the desirability of the stars included in the schedule according to the input.

Constraints:

1 ≤ N ≤ 10^4

0 ≤ Si,Fi ≤ 10000

1 ≤ Di ≤ 5000

As far as I understand, in this case we can use the very known model of job scheduling, using dynamic programming.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include<bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std; 

struct Star 
{ 
    int S, F, D; 
}; 


bool comparataor(Star s1, Star s2) 
{ 
    return (s1.F < s2.F); 
} 


int main() 

{  
    Star *arr;
   long long int N;
    bool found=0;


    cin >>N;
    arr=new Star[N];

    for(long long i=0;i<N;i++)
      cin >>arr[i].S>>arr[i].F>>arr[i].D; 


    sort(arr, arr+N, comparataor); 

    long long int *table = new long long int[N]; 
    table[0] = arr[0].D; 


    for (long long int i=1; i<N; i++) 
    { 
        long long int inclDesireability = arr[i].D; 
         long long  int l;
        found=0;
         long long int lo = 0, hi = i - 1; 

      while (lo <= hi && found==0) 
      { 
        long long int mid = (lo + hi) / 2; 
        if (arr[mid].F <= arr[i].S) 
        { 
            if (arr[mid + 1].F <= arr[i].S) 
                lo = mid + 1; 
            else
                {l= mid; 
                 found=1;
                }
        } 
        else
            hi = mid - 1; 
    }   

        if (found==1)
            inclDesireability += table[l]; 

        table[i] = max(inclDesireability, table[i-1]); 
    }



    cout<<table[N-1]<<endl; 
    delete[] table; 

    delete[] arr; 

   return 0;
}
```

It seems that the code runs well but:

there  are some tests which fail this code, but I can not detect why, I only know it fails...

(it's from the site of csacademy -competitive program )

Comment: Don't do that: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` It's an implementation header. It is not meant to be included.

Comment: Maybe it would help you in the long run to think up examples with which to test your program? Being able to conceive of the corner cases while designing your code is a useful skill that starts by devising them after you wrote code that failed. Once you find a case that fails, it should be easier to fix the code.

Comment: sounds like a variation of TSP problem to me

Comment: @Spektre omg you are right!  thank u !

Answer (score 1):

I would first wonder what they mean by "intersects".  Your `latestNonConflict` will include as not a conflict if the finishing time of one matches the starting time of the next.  But should that be a strict < instead?

Also what happens if you have the intervals `[1, 3], [4, 5], [2,6]`.  Is it possible that when you process the second you add the first to `inclDesireability` and then `[2, 6]` processes that overlapping interval?

Secondly you have a `O(N^2)` algorithm.  Perhaps that needs to be `O(n log(n))`?  You can get that using a heap structure, see [make_heap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/) for more.  Here is the idea.

We have two kinds of events.  Interval `i` starts, and interval `i` finishes.  They can be ordered by time first, then start before finish.  In pseudo-code:

```
best_schedule = empty schedule with desirability 0
for each interval i:
    make event_begin {is_start: True, interval: i, time: i.start, desirable: i.desirable, history: null}
    push event_begin onto events
make events into heap
while events not empty:
    event = pop_heap(events)
    if event.is_start:
        create event_finish {is_start: False, interval: i, time: i.start, desirable: best_schedule.desirable + i.desirable, history: best_schedule}
        events.push_heap(event_finish)
    else:
        if best_schedule.desirable < event.desirable:
            replace best_schedule with event.history followed by event.interval

best_schedule should be best possible.
```